Identify movie: drama romance, kind of dark indie film. Late 80s or early 90s
Man meets woman, they have fast and furious love relationship, eventually she leaves him. Movie is rated R, but there was an unusual scene where (as I recall) she brings a sex device to his apartment - a device you strap on with a belt - the kind a woman might use on another woman.
At the very end he is writing to her and the voiceover is something like, "I love you. I love you. Oh how I love you". I seem to remember him suffering writers block.

To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the movie or TV show (even an approximate year or decade is helpful), and what movies or TV shows you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Could this be "The Unbearable Lightness of Being" (1988) or  "Love and Human Remains" (1993)?
